# cannot pass a list of int as a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I am using DBeaber 6.0.3 and trying to make this query

```
declare @samplesList table (id int);
insert @samplesList(id) values(1121),(2121),(3121); 

SELECT *
FROM samples
where samplesId in (select id from @samplesList)
```

However I get a Sintax Error
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no such thing as a table variable in mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL v8, you can reproduce your example this way:

```
with samplesList as (
  select 1121 as id union all
  select 2121 union all
  select 3121 
)
SELECT *
FROM samples
where samplesId in (select id from samplesList)
```

Or in any version of MySQL:

```
create temporary table samplesList (id int);
insert into samplesList(id) values(1121),(2121),(3121);

SELECT *
FROM samples
where samplesId in (select id from samplesList)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get this error:  Table 'my.connection.samplesList' doesn't exist

Comment: Hi. Maybe it was a case issue. I have replaced the samplelist in with clause by sampleList. Hope it works now.